# How to get the number of months based on the weeks chosen in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a JQuery slider where I can choose the number of weeks. I want the months count once the slider crosses the corresponding weeks. For Eg. once the slider crosses 4 weeks, I need the month value as Month 1. Once it crosses 8 - 9 weeks, I need the month value as Month 2. Need JQuery script for this.

```
<div id="numberofmonth"></div> Months
<script> 
       $(function() {
       $( "#slider-6" ).slider({
       slide: function( event, ui ) {                     
             var week = ui.values[1];
             $( ".weeks" ).html(week);
       });
    });
</script>
```

I need the number of Months to be show up in the div of id "numberofmonth"

Comment: Please add your code snippet so we can help you :-)

Comment: console.log(ui); and see if there number of month available or not

Comment: can u user fiddle or snippet so that we and understand better

Answer (score 0):

Get your slider value into a variable and divide it by 4:

```
currentValue = ui.values[0];
var month= Math.floor(currentValue / 4);


//$( ".months" ).html(month);
```